# Как убрать кавычки при вставке многострочного текста из Excel в текстовый редактор?

Tags: excel

Если содержимое ячейки многострочное, например:

```
Жил-был
Вася.
```

То при копировании ячейки и вставке в текстовый файл, содержимое ячейки вставится с кавычками:

```
"Жил-был
Вася."
```

Как этого избежать? Генерирую xml файлик из таблицы и после копирования и вставки столбца приходится делать автозамену по всему файлу " менять на , а " менять на , например. Если содержимое ячеек однострочное, то автоматически с кавычками не вставляется в текстовики.

Comment: При обычном копировании данных ячейки и вставке в текстовый файл кавычки не появляются (даже если в ячейке несколько строк). Уточните.

Comment: Никаких дополнительных уточнений. В ячейке две строки (alt+enter между ними). Выделил ячейку (не провалился в неё), Ctrl+C, переключаюсь на блокнот, Ctrl+V - перед первой строй воткнулись кавычки и в конце последней. Не влияет то, формулой ли получена ячейка или там константа.

Comment: Без проваливания - да, есть такое... Кодом, наверное... Простых решений не знаю.